# What are the most common Python docstring formats?

Tags: python, coding-style, documentation, docstring

I have seen a few different styles of writing docstrings in Python, what are the most popular styles?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ there's a whole section devoted to documentation strings

Comment: I think that this question was not clear enough because PEP-257 and PEP-8 are the establishing only the base for docstrings, but how about `epydoc`, `doxygen`, `sphinx`? Does anyone have any statistics, is one of them going to replace the others, in cases like this too many options can hurt.

Comment: @sorin, I also would like to know what markup, if any, is most common.  But I think the answer is that none of them is really all that common: people tend to prefer to look at the Python source directly, rather than converted to html.  So, it's most useful to just be consistent but in a way that's optimized for human readability, and no explicit markup.

Comment: PyCharm autocompletes in a rather interesting way, which I think is a nice implementation of the instructions needed to run it:
`def foo(self, other):\n\t"""\n\t(blank line)\n\t:param other: \n\t:return:\n\t"""`

Comment: Which of these answers is the one that works by default with the VS Code documentation parser?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken At least google style works in VS Code, didn't check others.

Answer (score 1389, accepted):

## Formats

Python docstrings can be written following several formats as the other posts showed. However the default Sphinx docstring format was not mentioned and is based on **reStructuredText (reST)**. You can get some information about the main formats in [this blog post](http://daouzli.com/blog/docstring.html).

Note that the reST is recommended by the [PEP 287](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287)

There follows the main used formats for docstrings.

### - Epytext

Historically a **javadoc** like style was prevalent, so it was taken as a base for [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net) (with the called `Epytext` format) to generate documentation.

Example:

```
"""
This is a javadoc style.

@param param1: this is a first param
@param param2: this is a second param
@return: this is a description of what is returned
@raise keyError: raises an exception
"""
```

### - reST

Nowadays, the probably more prevalent format is the **reStructuredText** (reST) format that is used by [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org) to generate documentation.
Note: it is used by default in JetBrains PyCharm (type triple quotes after defining a method and hit enter). It is also used by default as output format in Pyment.

Example:

```
"""
This is a reST style.

:param param1: this is a first param
:param param2: this is a second param
:returns: this is a description of what is returned
:raises keyError: raises an exception
"""
```

### - Google

Google has their own [format](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#38-comments-and-docstrings) that is often used. It also can be interpreted by Sphinx (ie. using [Napoleon plugin](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

Example:

```
"""
This is an example of Google style.

Args:
    param1: This is the first param.
    param2: This is a second param.

Returns:
    This is a description of what is returned.

Raises:
    KeyError: Raises an exception.
"""
```

Even [more examples](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/example_google.html#example-google)

### - Numpydoc

Note that Numpy recommend to follow their own [numpydoc](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) based on Google format and usable by Sphinx.

```
"""
My numpydoc description of a kind
of very exhautive numpydoc format docstring.

Parameters
----------
first : array_like
    the 1st param name `first`
second :
    the 2nd param
third : {'value', 'other'}, optional
    the 3rd param, by default 'value'

Returns
-------
string
    a value in a string

Raises
------
KeyError
    when a key error
OtherError
    when an other error
"""
```

## Converting/Generating

It is possible to use a tool like [Pyment](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment) to automatically generate docstrings to a Python project not yet documented, or to convert existing docstrings (can be mixing several formats) from a format to an other one.

Note: The examples are taken from the [Pyment documentation](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment/blob/master/README.rst)

Comment: I might add that reST is what's used by default in JetBrains PyCharm, Just type triple quotes after defining your method and hit enter.https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-documentation-comments.html

Comment: Most comprehensive answer, includes a sense of history and current best practices.  Now all we need is some sense of community motion toward a new "best" format and some additional community effort toward creating migration tools from all the othersto the new one, so we could actually evolve best practice.

Comment: yo @daouzli, google style link is 404. I belive [this one](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Comments) is correct. You can add [sphinx google style example](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/example_google.html) as well. Great answer btw. EDIT: I edited your answer by myself.

Comment: good answer. I dare say where you can change default docstring format in PyCharm (JetBrains):

Settings --> Tools --> Python Integrated Tools --> Docstring format. Good luck!

Comment: I'm surprised noone commented about the first text line: currently it's strictly speaking correct but i feel like the prefered way is to place it on the first line just after the triple quotes. PEP 8 and PEP 257 does it in almost all of their examples. PEP 287 does it your way, but in my experience it is not that common.

Comment: I lean more towards reST in Python although I really like the way Epytext makes use of the `@` character more readable compared to reST's `:`. Oh well, must be my PHP doppelganger trying to come out again.

Comment: PyCharm: you can define (per project!) which Docstring format PyCharm will generate, just go to Settings / Tools / Python Integrated Tools  and, in the "Docstrings" section, select your format of choice.

Comment: I prefer Google format, which is really good to read, and does not use so much vertical space as Numpydoc does. Epytext format is IMHO the same higgledy-piggledy mess as reST format.

Comment: To get [Sphinx](https://sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to parse Google format, use the [napoleon](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin

Comment: I'm very surprised Google used "Args" and not "Params" or "Parameters".  There are two distinct differences.  Parameters are the variables of a function whereas arguments are the values of the parameters when invoked.  So their label means they're using the value, not the variable as metadata for docstring.

Answer (score 354):

The [Google style guide](https://github.com/google/styleguide) contains an excellent Python style guide. It includes [conventions for readable docstring syntax](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#38-comments-and-docstrings) that offers better guidance than PEP-257. For example:

```
def square_root(n):
    """Calculate the square root of a number.

    Args:
        n: the number to get the square root of.
    Returns:
        the square root of n.
    Raises:
        TypeError: if n is not a number.
        ValueError: if n is negative.

    """
    pass
```

I like to extend this to also include type information in the arguments, as described in this [Sphinx documentation tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#full-code-example). For example:

```
def add_value(self, value):
    """Add a new value.

       Args:
           value (str): the value to add.
    """
    pass
```

Comment: I find the "signature in docstrings"-style awfully redundant and verbose. For Python 3+, [Function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) are a much cleaner way to do this. Even worse if it uses pseudo-strong-types: Python is way better with duck typing.

Comment: yeah, but at least it gives a hint of what sort of duck is expected, and majority of devs aren't on Python 3 yet

Comment: @Evpok personally, I don't like function annotations. To use classes in them you might have to do unnecessary imports, to use strings in them you might run out of horizontal space very quickly describing them. So far I haven't seen the point of using them for anything.

Comment: @OdraEncoded I only use them when a type is crucial, which is not often. But usually a short sentence in *natural language and not pseudo-javadoc* is better, I agree.

Comment: @Nathan, Google's style guide recommends comments that are descriptive rather than declarative, e.g. "Fetches rows from a Bigtable" over "Fetch rows from a Bigtable." Thus, changing "Calculate..." to "Calculates..." would make your example more consistent with the rest of the comment, i.e. "Returns" and "Raises".

Comment: nit: Following Google style, use descriptive rather than imperative form, i.e. "Calculates ..." and "Adds ..."

Comment: does anyone why Google is naming them Args rather than Parameters ?

Answer (score 244):

Docstring conventions are in [PEP-257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) with much more detail than PEP-8.

However, docstrings seem to be far more personal than other areas of code. Different projects will have their own standard.

I tend to always include docstrings, because they tend to demonstrate how to use the function and what it does very quickly.

I prefer to keep things consistent, regardless of the length of the string. I like how to code looks when indentation and spacing are consistent. That means, I use:

```
def sq(n):
    """
    Return the square of n. 
    """
    return n * n
```

Over:

```
def sq(n):
    """Returns the square of n."""
    return n * n
```

And tend to leave off commenting on the first line in longer docstrings:

```
def sq(n):
    """
    Return the square of n, accepting all numeric types:

    >>> sq(10)
    100

    >>> sq(10.434)
    108.86835599999999

    Raises a TypeError when input is invalid:

    >>> sq(4*'435')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

    """
    return n*n
```

Meaning I find docstrings that start like this to be messy.

```
def sq(n):
    """Return the squared result. 
    ...
```

Comment: Note that PEP-8 specifically says that the docstrings should be written as commands/instructions, rather than descriptions, eg. `"""Return the squared result"""` rather than `"""Returns the squared result"""`. Although personally, I write mine how Tim's are here, despite what the PEP says.

Comment: I also don't agree with that advice (using the imperative tense) because it starts sounding awkward for anything longer than one sentence. Furthermore, you are *describing* a function, not telling the reader what to do.

Comment: _Note: The specification for prescriptive rather than descriptive docstrings actually appears in [PEP-257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings), not PEP-8._

I've come from a tradition of Java, where I was describing functions, but I finally began using the imperative tense when my programming paradigm switched from object-oriented to procedural. And when I began using [pycco](http://fitzgen.github.io/pycco/) to generate literate-programming-style documentation, it became very apparent why the imperative tense was suggested. You should choose based on your paradigm.

Comment: [PEP-257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings) says "One-liners are for really obvious cases. They should really fit on one line."

Comment: The imperative is a grammatical *mood*. (Sorry.)

Comment: @Mk12 Git commit messages should also be written as commands instead of descriptions.  And they are also "*describing*" a code change, "not telling the reader what to do".  So I think it is just convention to write descriptions as commands.

Comment: Mentioning PEP-257 in the context of "how should i properly document parameters, return values, exceptions raised etc" is a JOKE - it says not a single word about them (although a code example shows some). IMHO Google Format is a good choice with regard to readability and features.

Comment: I like to think of it as querying the function: "what do you do?"

From this perspective, it makes more sense to describe it as the first person indicative with the pronouns stripped (because they're implicit):
"Function X, what do you do?"
I....
"Return the square of a number"

Same for commits.

Answer (score 67):

As apparantly no one mentioned it: you can also use the **Numpy Docstring Standard**. It is widely used in the scientific community.

- The [specification of the format](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard) from numpy together with an [example](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/example.py)
- You have a sphinx extension to render it: [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc)
- And an example of how beautiful a rendered docstring can look like: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

The Napolean sphinx extension to parse Google-style docstrings (recommended in the answer of @Nathan) also supports Numpy-style docstring, and makes a short [comparison](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#google-vs-numpy) of both.

And last a basic example to give an idea how it looks like:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
    """Summary line.

    Extended description of function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arg1 : int
        Description of arg1
    arg2 : str
        Description of arg2

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        Description of return value

    See Also
    --------
    otherfunc : some related other function

    Examples
    --------
    These are written in doctest format, and should illustrate how to
    use the function.

    >>> a=[1,2,3]
    >>> print [x + 3 for x in a]
    [4, 5, 6]
    """
    return True
```

Comment: NumPy format IMHO takes too much vertical space which is scarce on widescreen monitors (except you use one turned by 90 degrees, but i guess most people don't) So, IMHO Google Format is a good choice with regard to readability and features.

Comment: I suppose it is somewhat subjective. Once you have a more complex docstring (with different sections, with examples, etc, so taking a lot of vertical space anyhow regardless of the format), I find the numpydoc format easier to read / better structured.

Comment: Personally I feel such a long docstring is better located in the documentation, not the source code, if it is so long they end up impeding readability of the module.

Answer (score 12):

It's Python; [anything goes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2VTR86_iOM). Consider how to *publish your documentation*. Docstrings are invisible except to readers of your source code.

People really like to browse and search documentation on the web. To achieve that, use the documentation tool [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/). It's the de-facto standard for documenting Python projects. The product is beautiful - take a look at https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ . The website [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) will host your docs for free.

Comment: I routinely use `ipython` to test-drive a library, and it makes reading docstrings dead simple — all I have to type is `your_module.some_method_im_curious_about?` and I get a every nice printout, including docstring.

Comment: The users of a *library* or of an *API* or who are writing a *plugin* are all likely to look at the code and need to make sense of it. I find comments far more crucial in Python than in Java or C# because types are not declared. It helps a lot if the comments give an idea of roughly what kinds of ducks are being passed and returned. (Otherwise, you have to actually walk all the code and tally up that a given parameter must... be iterable over here... support indexing over there... support numeric subtraction at the end... Aha! It's basically an int array. A comment would've helped!)

Comment: Eh, no. Docstrings are **not** invisible and that's a bit of the point. You get to see the docstring if you run the `help` function on the documented function/method/class (and that you can do even if you only have access to the compiled module). Personally I think one should keep this in mind when choosing docstring convention (ie that it's intented to be read as is).

Comment: NB: The linked video has been removed.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using Vladimir Keleshev's [pep257](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep257) Python program to check your docstrings against [PEP-257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) and the [Numpy Docstring Standard](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt) for describing parameters, returns, etc.

pep257 will report divergence you make from the standard and is called like pylint and pep8.

Comment: Mentioning PEP-257 in the context of "how should i properly document parameters, return values, exceptions raised etc" is a JOKE - it says not a single word about them (although a code example shows some).
NumPy format IMHO takes too much vertical space which is scarce on widescreen monitors (except you use one turned by 90 degrees, but i guess most people don't)
So, IMHO Google Format is a good choice with regard to readability and features.

Comment: @Semanino I am mentioning the Numpy Docstring Standard in the context of the pep257 program, - not PEP-257. That program is now called pydocstyle. pydocstyle allows you to do some numpydoc checks, e.g., `pydocstyle --select=D4 tmp.py` checks for a range of docstring content issues including section naming.