# Python inspect.getargspec with built-in function

Tags: python, function, methods, arguments, inspect

I'm trying to figure out the arguments of a method retrieved from a module.
I found an `inspect` module with a handy function, `getargspec`.
It works for a function that I define, but won't work for functions from an imported module.

```
import math, inspect
def foobar(a,b=11): pass
inspect.getargspec(foobar)  # this works
inspect.getargspec(math.sin) # this doesn't
```

I'll get an error like this:

```
   File "C:\...\Python 2.5\Lib\inspect.py", line 743, in getargspec
     raise TypeError('arg is not a Python function')
 TypeError: arg is not a Python function
```

Is `inspect.getargspec` designed only for local functions or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yes, it's designed this way, see http://bugs.python.org/issue1748064

Answer (score 14):

It is impossible to get this kind of information for a function that is implemented in C instead of Python.

The reason for this is that there is no way to find out what arguments the method accepts except by parsing the (free-form) docstring since arguments are passed in a (somewhat) getarg-like way - i.e. it's impossible to find out what arguments it accepts without actually executing the function.

Comment: Okay, I'm gettin back to this. So is there even any dirty way to do it. If it requires calling the function, it's okay.

Comment: **No**, not really. You could only bruteforce some arguments where calling the function does not raise an exception. But that's hardly useful - you wouldn't even know if there are some optional arguments you didn't try etc.

Comment: Alrite. Thanks. I need to find another way.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the doc string for such functions/methods which nearly always contains the same type of information as getargspec. (I.e. param names, no. of params, optional ones, default values).

In your example

```
import math
math.sin.__doc__
```

Gives

```
"sin(x)

Return the sine of x (measured in radians)"
```

Unfortunately there are several different standards in operation. See [What is the standard Python docstring format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format)

You could detect which of the standards is in use, and then grab the info that way. From the above link it looks like [pyment](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment) could be helpful in doing just that.