# How to introspect a function defined in a Cython C extension module

Tags: python, cython, introspection, python-c-extension

Python's [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module doesn't seem to be able to inspect the signatures of "built-in" functions, which include functions defined in C extension modules, like those defined by Cython. Is there any way to get the signature of a Python function you have defined in such a module, and specifically in Cython? I am looking to be able to find the available keyword arguments.

MWE:

```
# mwe.pyx
def example(a, b=None):                                                                                                                                                       
    pass
```

and

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()                                                                                                                                         
import mwe                                                                                                                                                                    
import inspect                                                                                                                                                                

inspect.signature(mwe.example)
```

yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                           
  File "mwe_py.py", line 5, in <module>                                                                                                                                      
    inspect.signature(mwe.example)                                                                                                                                           
  File "/nix/store/134l79vxb91w8mhxxkj6kb5llf7dmwpm-python3-3.4.5/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 2063, in signature                                                         
    return _signature_internal(obj)                                                                                                                                          
  File "/nix/store/134l79vxb91w8mhxxkj6kb5llf7dmwpm-python3-3.4.5/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 1965, in _signature_internal                                               
    skip_bound_arg=skip_bound_arg)                                                                                                                                           
  File "/nix/store/134l79vxb91w8mhxxkj6kb5llf7dmwpm-python3-3.4.5/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 1890, in _signature_from_builtin                                           
    raise ValueError("no signature found for builtin {!r}".format(func))                                                                                                     
ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function example>
```

In Python 3.4.5 and Cython 0.24.1

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? `inspect.signature(all)` (for example to extract the signature of [`all`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all)) works great `<Signature (iterable, /)>`. Please provide an [mcve] so that answers can actually show you how to do it in *your case*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python inspect.getargspec with built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343191/python-inspect-getargspec-with-built-in-function)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104823/python-c-extension-method-signatures-for-documentation

Comment: @DavidW Thanks, I have seen these answers, but had wondered if Cython adds some magic to make this work. Sorry, probably should have included in the question

Comment: @MSeifert I have updated with an MWE. If you voted -1, would you mind reversing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've retracted my duplicate suggestion (saying that it was impossible...) having investigated further. It seems to work fine with reasonably recent versions of Cython (v0.23.4) and Python 3.4.4.

```
import cython
import inspect
scope = cython.inline("""def f(a,*args,b=False): pass """)
print(inspect.getfullargspec(scope['f']))
```

gives the output

> `FullArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs='args', varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['b'], kwonlydefaults={'b': False}, annotations={})`

---

Also mentioned in [the documentation is the compilation option "`binding`"](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives) which apparently makes this detail more accessible (although I didn't need it).

---

I have a feeling that this may depend on improvements to `inspect` made relatively recently (possibly [this fix](http://bugs.python.org/issue17481)) so if you're using Python 2 you're probably out of luck.

---

**Edit:** your example works if you using the `binding` compilation option:

```
import cython
@cython.binding(True)
def example(a, b=None):                                                                                                                                                       
    pass
```

I suspect that `inline` adds it automatically (but the code to do `inline` is sufficiently convoluted that I can't find proof of that either way). You can also set it as a file-level option.

Comment: Thanks David, I have updated the question with an MWE, doesn't seem to work with an import as opposed to inline function.

Comment: @Gilly See edit - it's just a case of making sure you use `binding`

Comment: Thanks a heap! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `getfullargspec` and `signature` don't seem to get the keyword arguments correctly for `cdef` class methods, though they do for `pyx` module functions. The keyword arguments appear as if they are positional arguments. These functions do get the names of arguments correctly for module functions.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis I was just about to tell you that it might be worth filling a bug, but it looks like you've already done that...

Comment: Does anyone know if this can be done in python 2.7? `getfullargspec` works only from python 3 on

Answer (score 2):

The answer above using the binding decorator works for me when running code that has been cythonized. But, when I was running that same code within a Django 2.2 app, the application would fail on start with an error that cython has no attribute 'binding'. To avoid this I have added this "special cython header" at the top of my file containing the cythonized function as documented [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#globally) to achieve the same results.

```
# cython: binding=True

def example(a, b=None):                                                                                                                                                       
    pass
```