# How to get signatures of Python types like Exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get the signature of `Exception.__init__` using `inspect` module but using `inspect` module on Python types like `Exception`  and `None` fails with the below error.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc in getargspec(func)
    814         func = func.im_func
    815     if not isfunction(func):
--> 816         raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
    817     args, varargs, varkw = getargs(func.func_code)
    818     return ArgSpec(args, varargs, varkw, func.func_defaults)

TypeError: <method-wrapper '__init__' of NoneType object at 0x8ff8d0>
is not a Python function
```

I would like to know how signatures of in-built functions of types defined in Python can be obtained.

Comment: Can you include the offending code, and format all code and tracebacks in a code block?

Comment: Obtained from the documentation :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python inspect.getargspec with built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343191/python-inspect-getargspec-with-built-in-function)

Comment: @Zizouz212 not sure whether module functions and functions of in-build type should fall in same category

Comment: @wim I could not find the same in documentation. I found that the link https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html?highlight=exception#exceptions.BaseException has partial info but not exactly the signature.

Comment: `None` is not a type.

Comment: @user2357112 in Python `None` is a in-built type

Comment: @darth_coder: No, it is not. If you check `isinstance(None, type)`, you will get `False`. If you check `isinstance(3, None)` or `isinstance(any_object_here, None)`, you will get an error message complaining about how `None` is not a type or a tuple of types.

Comment: @user2357112 but `type(None)` gives output as `NoneType`

Comment: `NoneType` is a type. It is `None`'s type. That doesn't mean that `None` itself is a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, `inspect` does not work on functions or classes implemented in C, as they do not have the necessary object attributes for `inspect` to obtain details from.

This has been fixed in Python 3.x.

Comment: But what is the solution for Python 2.7 then

Comment: There's no way to work around this in Python 2.7 since there's no annotation member for any of the C-implemented functions in the source code.

Comment: Even the documentation is not that helpful

Comment: The documentation doesn't matter. It's just that there's no implementation of the annotation interface in the source code of any of the C functions in Python 2.7.