# How to write help/description text for Python functions

Tags: python, function, spyder

I recently started programming using Python. I have to write many functions and was wondering how I can incorporate a help or description text such that it appears in the object inspector of spyder when I call the function.
In MatLab, this worked by putting commented text at the beginning of the function file. Is there a similar method in Python (using Spyder)?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

By default, the first string in the body of a method is used as its docstring (or documentation string). Python will use this when `help()` is called for that method.

```
def foo(bar):
    """
    Takes bar and does some things to it.
    """
    return bar

help(foo)
foo(bar)
    Takes bar and does
    some things to it
```

You can read more about how this works by reading [PEP-258](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0258/), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format) goes into some more details.

Comment: how to do it for packages?

Answer (score 11):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There are other couple of things you need to know (besides what @burhan-khalid mentioned) regarding Spyder itself:

1. If you want to see your docstrings nicely formatted in the Help pane, you need to write them following the `numpydoc` standard, which is explained [here](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard). This is a set of conventions used by almost all python scientific packages to write their docstrings. It's not mandatory but we follow it too while converting docstrings (which come in plain text) to html.
2. You have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in front of an object's name to show their help in our Help pane.

Comment: I've found this very helpful, thanks! Is this the new place for that? https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard

Answer (score 7):

In a short answer. This can be done by putting text between triple quotes.

```
'''
@param self
'''
```

You can find a brief example on this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-documentation-comments.html#

The other answers are more extensive.