# Can't render python reST format docstring

Tags: python, format, restructuredtext, docstring

I was studying a python framework, scrapy and I learned that it uses a style of docstring as below

```
class CrawlerRunner(__builtin__.object)
 |  This is a convenient helper class that keeps track of, manages and runs
 |  crawlers inside an already setup Twisted `reactor`_.
 |  
 |  The CrawlerRunner object must be instantiated with a
 |  :class:`~scrapy.settings.Settings` object.
 |  
 |  __init__(self, settings=None)
 |  
 |  crawl(self, crawler_or_spidercls, *args, **kwargs)
 |      Run a crawler with the provided arguments.
 |      
 |      It will call the given Crawler's :meth:`~Crawler.crawl` method, while
 |      keeping track of it so it can be stopped later.
```

I wondered what all those special characters do or mean. I came upon [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format) and kinda had vague idea of what reST format is. I wanted to know how this docstring is supposed to be rendered so tried this [online renderer](http://rst.ninjs.org/) but it didn't render the doctstring properly. seemed like it didn't support things such as :class: and :meth:

**My questions are**

- Why couldn't I render the docstring. Isn't it valid reST format?
- Isn't this style of docstring supposed to be rendered at all? Or
  should it be read as plain text?
- How can I render this if I can?
- Is it possible to have rendered docstring in interactive python shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why couldn't I render the docstring. Isn't it valid reST format?

The reST is valid but it contains markup that is not part of "standard reST", which is what the http://rst.ninjs.org/ renderer supports (it [uses](http://rst.ninjs.org/about) rst2html.py, provided by [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/)).

`:class:` and `:meth:` are examples of additions to standard reST that are understood by the Sphinx documentation generator. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/index.html and http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html.

The following markup,

```
:class:`~scrapy.settings.Settings`
```

is rendered as a hyperlink to the documentation of the `scrapy.settings.Settings` class. See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.3/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner.

> Isn't this style of docstring supposed to be rendered at all? Or should it be read as plain text?
>
> How can I render this if I can?

The docstring is supposed to be processed by Sphinx.

> Is it possible to have rendered docstring in interactive python shell?

I suppose that it is possible to implement something that makes the console output nicer, but I don't know any tool or library that does this.