# Do I need to do type checking when preparing library for open source?

Tags: python, exception, open-source

I have I small module that I use inside one of my projects. Now I decided to place it on github so now I am writing some docstrings and cleaning the code.

I have a composition of 2 classes so the initialization looks like this:

```
foo = Class_1()
bar = Class_2(param1=foo)
```

I know that the first argument to the `Class_2` has to be an instance of `Class_1` or the code won't work. But it may be clear only for me as I wrote code of `Class_2`, but when using module as API it may be unclear for a user that `param1` has to be an instance of `Class_1`. If someone will use `bar = Class_2(param1='foo')`. The trackback will be bad and it will be impossible to understand what happened. So the question is: do I need to check in my `__init__` that `isinstance(param1, Class_1)` and if no raise an excaption with an appropriate message, or writing good documentation is enough?

Comment: Since at least X% of your users won't read the documentation, and since good code should be both self-documenting and prevent users from wrong usage - it's much preferable to change your algorithm to prevent *known* bugs. We have enough *unknown* bugs to worry of.

Answer (score 0):

This is very opinion-based (not great for StackOverflow in particular) - but in my opinion, you should do both.

On the one hand, using `isinstance()` and exception-handling are both good defensive-coding practices.

On the other hand, inline documentation is nice.  Per the [Python developer guide](https://devguide.python.org/documenting/):

> The markup used for the Python documentation is reStructuredText, developed by the docutils project, amended by custom directives and using a toolset named Sphinx to post-process the HTML output.

Some IDEs, such as JetBrains PyCharm, are configured to automatically pick up well-formed `reST` docstrings and perform automated type-checking based on those conventions (which I've found to be really useful). See also: [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) and [What is the standard Python docstring format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format) for details.