# Colons at beginning of lines in Python comments

Tags: python, comments

What's the function of the colon : before return here? Is that a style thing in Python?

> ```
> def close(self):
>     """ Close this connection.
>     :returns: None
>     """
>     self.conn.close()
>     return
> ```

Comment: I think it would work the same with or without the colons

Comment: It looks like the kind of thing you see in documentation-oriented markup languages, like Restructured Text, where syntax like that is used to do stuff like make `returns` show up in italics or fixed-width when generating HTML docs from docstrings.  I'm not sure which particular documentation-generation library that is from though.

Comment: Agree with @BrenBarn and @chngzm . This is a comment section which was written to be friendly to documentation-generation. Nothing to do with the code structure or python. You can write `"Mary had a :: little :: lamb"` and it would work fine!

Comment: This is not python style. It's just a comment which means the method returns None.

Answer (score 5):

Because it is in a docstring (enclosed in triple quotes) it is just like a comment and doesn't do anything other than document your code.

There are various conventions of writing docstrings - this is one of them (the reST format used by [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/)).

The colons are typically used to describe what parameters the function expects and what the function returns, like so:

```
"""
This is a reST style.

:param param1: this is a first param
:param param2: this is a second param
:returns: this is a description of what is returned
:raises keyError: raises an exception
"""
```

In this case it says that the function is expected to return None.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format) post for more details on the various conventions.

Comment: This is the correct answer, it is just a docstring, read the PEP-8 for it [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

Answer (score 0):

On some IDEs (namely PyCharm) if you type type triple quotes and then enter below a function signature the IDE will automatically document parameters and return value of the function/method in the style you show. They are called [document comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-documentation-comments.html) and will allow the IDE to present hover-over information about a parameter/return value when used elsewhere.

This documentation style has no effect on program behavior.