# How can i know what parameters i can pass to a python function and what is the proper values?

Tags: python, arguments

For example, when i use matplotlib as plt, a possible statement is like below:

plt.plot(x,y,color='blue')

so how can i get what arguments like 'color' i can pass to the 'plot' function, and what is the proper values for that  argument?

Especially when i use some modules.

thanks for any answers.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: Have you even tried searching Google? The very first for `matplotlib` hit is the documentation!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tahnks for your answering. I guess Python should provide some tools to list those information like help() and inspect module. But i don't know the precise usage. e.g. help(plt.xlabel) doesn't  give enough arguments details. what should i do to get those details other than reading documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little disappointed that this post is being downvoted because I think it's a very legitimate question. In particular, I appreciate that you asked not *what* the answer was but instead *how* you could find it for yourself in the future.

### Exploring Local Python Documentation

Python has a very robust built-in documentation system as well as a very active and supportive community. At any point in time, you can use the [`help`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) function to examine a particular object that you want more information on - this will pull up the documentation for that object. In your example, you could do something like:

```
help(plt.plot)
```

to pull up the documentation for the [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) function. Outside of a running Python process, you can use the `pydoc` command line tool to read and explore that same documentation. Something like:

```
$ pydoc matplotlib.pyplot.plot
```

Running that in the shell will display the same documentation as the `help` command example.

#### Writing Documentation

As a good citizen of the Python ecosystem, you'll naturally want to document your *own* code. This is done pretty simply by adding a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to the top of a function, class, or module. Docstrings are denoted with a triple quotation mark `"""`, seen in the examples below:

```
"""This module contains some example classes and functions"""

class MyClass(object):
    """MyClass does some things"""
    pass

def my_function(a):
    """Calculates the sum"""
    return(a)
```

There are [many different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24385103/9190971) documentation styles that people prefer, so what you choose is up to you. Though I would recommend the [official docstring standards outlined in PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

### Finding Online Resources

It's also often useful to take advantage of online documentation and resources. The [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) includes all of the builtin documentation for the standard libraries as well as a tutorial for developers who are new to Python!

As it seems that you're relatively new to the ecosystem yourself, here's some more resources that you might find useful:

- [Learn Python the Hard Way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/)
- CodeAcademy has a [Python track](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python)
- [StackOverflow, obviously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried help(plt.plot) and i do get useful help. But when i try 'help(plt.xlabel)', I didn't get enough arguments details(only 3 override arguments). How is this going？ does it mean xlabel doesn't support other arguments? What should i do in this situation? I tried inspect module, too. only inspect.getmembers can give all arguments but with so many redundant message. I am new to python. Really thank you for answering such beginner's question so patiently.