# Is there a way to see which interface a parameter has to implement in python

Tags: python, interface, duck-typing

Given methods:

```
def foo(bar):
    bar.buzz()
    bar.blep()

def bla(bee):
    bee.buzz()
```

Now, we know that `bar` has to have `buzz` and `blep` methods. But the clients of the code does not know that unless they open the implementation and read through it (which can be easy in this example but can be tricky in the real world).

One solution is to define an `ABC`, like so:

```
def BuzzBlepable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def buzz():
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def blep():
        pass
```

Now we can have the code:

```
def foo(bar: BuzzBlepable):
    bar.buzz()
    bar.blep()

def bla(bee: BuzzBlepable):
    bee.buzz()
```

The problem with this is that `bla` method doesn't really need the `bee` parameter to implement `blep` method, but we will be forcing the client to do so anyway. This begs a question, is there any good practice to tell the client which interface the parameter has to conform to? Like, auto-generated method documentation or something? Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> This begs a question, is there any good practice to tell the client
>   which interface the parameter has to conform to? Like, auto-generated
>   method documentation or something?

I think you want to use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Docstrings can be used to describes modules, classes and methods. So you could describe the type of parameter the functions expects in a docstring and then describe the methods of a class in the docstring of this class. There are a couple of different sytles for docstrings,  you can find a discussion on them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format).

Using the google style, you could do something like this:

```
def foo(param1):
    """
    Description of the method

    Args:
        param1: Description of the param 

    """
```

The user can then use either `foo.__doc__` or `help(foo)` to see the documentation.
IDEs like PyCharm also have the ability to generate this docstring automatically. Alternatively, you can use tools like [Pyment](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment) to automatically generate your docstrings.

Comment: Thx for the Pyment suggestion, reading about it now. I think it is possible to automate it into creating the doctrings on every build. Although this wouldn't really solve the interface issue.