# :return: keyword inside comment

Tags: python, documentation

I was writing a comment inside the function and my IDE autocompleted it like this:

```
async def some_func():
    """

    :return:
    """
```

What is this :return: used for and where can I read more about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-are-the-most-common-python-docstring-formats (It's reST).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is part of the sphinx docstring format (there are many other format types like numpy, google, etc). this [link](https://sphinx-rtd-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docstrings.html) should help describe in detail.

these docstring specification help with auto documentation like you see with many python packages (eg [link](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/asyncstream.html) see "Returns" section)